# Json Data type without Stringify to MVC Controller

Tags: javascript, c#, json, asp.net-mvc

I have a MVC Controller that have a string as a parameter.

```
  [HttpPost]
        public string Index(string data)
        {




            return data.ToString();

        }
```

And a WebHook that will respond like this.

```
{"data":{"estimated_value":hello}}
```

The problem is the data is null when I debug on and I have no way of controlling the response as it is a Webhook and is controlled by another web app.

I try to use Postman that have a content-type of application/javascript as JSON

now If I try to post with this kind of json, I will get some data

```
{"data":"mydata"}
```

I will get a return of `mydata` so if the parameter `(string data)` will get the exact data object from the json, how can I get the entire thing as an Object. [WITHOUT CREATING A CLASS FOR SERIALIZATION] I would need it as either an Object or just plain string.

Also If I try to add more parameters, the first parameter is getting omitted. I might use class Creation for this but first I have to know how to get the data with

```
{"data":{"mydata":23232}}
```

this kind of format.

Steps that I have tried so far.
1. Create Class Xamasoft JSON Class Generator.
2. Change parameter to object: result {object};
3. Change parameter to JSONResult. Still null.
4. Added array string[]. Result. Still nothing;
5. added [System.Web.Http.FromBody] to the parameter. Same Result;

**UPDATED QUESTION**

So  Stephen Muecke had answered Correctly and Unfortunately it is in the comment again.

I would like to have an added Question for this Query so I would not have to ask again in a different Context.

So how can I get the Data if the json return is in this format.

`{"data":{"estimated_value":[{"index":0, "address": "128 myHome"},{"index":1, "address": "531 myappartment"}]   }`

Comment: Create a model (say `class DataModel`) with property `string Estimated_Value` and then in the controller `public string Index(DataModel data)`

Comment: You can also use Dynamic type parameter

Comment: @Steph, I will try the DataModel now. Bose. I read about the <Dynamic> Type or do you call it Generic type. I am not sure how to use it, But I will read on about it too. Be back with the Result. And as Usual if Steph answers, I would have to answer my own post again.

Comment: why you are using ToString() ? you must return data only. no conversion needed. so that u won't get any error at that time....

Comment: @StephenMuecke I have updated my Question, thanks for the comment it answered my first Problem. If it is not too much problem, please make an Answer so I can finally mark it.

Comment: Got it. I just made another class as a List. Thanks Steph